# Unstack and convert dates of observations to sequence number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV with one row for every observation per individual:

```
USER    DATE    SCORE
1   7/9/2015    37.2
1   11/18/2015  68.9
2   7/7/2015    45.1
2   11/2/2015   42.9
3   6/4/2015    56
3   10/27/2015  39
3   5/11/2016   42.9
```

I'd like to produce a dataframe where the first observation is assigned to round one, second to round two, and so forth. So the result would look like:

```
USER    R1      R2      R3
1       37.2    68.9    NaN
2       45.1    42.9    NaN
3       56      39      42.9
```

I've played around with pd.pivot and pd.unstack, but can't get what I need.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `apply` for creating new columns:

```
#if necessary sort values
df =  df.sort_values(by=['USER','DATE'])

df = df.groupby('USER')['SCORE'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values))
       .unstack()
       .rename(columns = lambda x: 'R' + str(x+1))
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   USER    R1    R2    R3
0     1  37.2  68.9   NaN
1     2  45.1  42.9   NaN
2     3  56.0  39.0  42.9
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
#if necessary sort values
df =  df.sort_values(by=['USER','DATE'])

df = pd.pivot(index=df['USER'],columns=df.groupby('USER').cumcount() + 1,values=df['SCORE'])
       .add_prefix('R')
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   USER    R1    R2    R3
0     1  37.2  68.9   NaN
1     2  45.1  42.9   NaN
2     3  56.0  39.0  42.9
```

Answer (score 0):

- First sort values by `USER` and `DATE` (this seems to be done already in example data but just to be sure).
- Then create a new column `ROUND` that will sequentially number entries for every user.
- Set index to columns `USER` and `ROUND`.
- Finally, unstack the `SCORE` column.

Here's some example code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''USER    DATE    SCORE
1   7/9/2015    37.2
1   11/18/2015  68.9
2   7/7/2015    45.1
2   11/2/2015   42.9
3   6/4/2015    56
3   10/27/2015  39
3   5/11/2016   42.9'''
df = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+',parse_dates=['DATE'])
        .sort_values(by=['USER','DATE'])
        .assign(ROUND = lambda x: x.groupby('USER').cumcount() + 1)
        .set_index(['USER','ROUND'])['SCORE']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('R')
     )
```